# Keep iPhone app opened in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, theos

As title says, i need to keep my iPhone app opened in background, i dont need to perform any task, just make it not start from new if not completely closed from multitasking (i.e. like native apps like Notes or Stocks do).
I added:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<false/>
```

to my Info.plist but it seems to be not enough. I placed NSLog to see what happens and i noticed that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is fired everytime the app gets, opened no matter if it was closed or not from multitasking. Also `applicationDidEnterBackground` gets fired but i see that `applicationWillTerminate` immediately follows. `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead is never fired.

Any ideas on how can i make backgounding of my app to work?

Side notes: i'm compiling with **theos** directly on the iPhone.

Comment: I don't know what theos is, but it is probably the source of the problem. Most apps since iOS 4 do not terminate after `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: This is theos: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos

Comment: I don't care what it is. What I'm telling you is that if you build an iPhone app the normal way, with Xcode, it won't normally terminate in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your app running in the background with the iOS 7 Multitasking API.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

You can set your app to run in the background by adding the UIBackgroundModes key to your Info.plist, settings it's value to an array, and adding app states to the array (link above)

Comment: That's where all the stuff i'm talking about in my question comes from. Unfortunatley this doesnt really help me understand why my app gets terminated instead of entering background :-/ but thanks anyway

Comment: @Fabius Have you looked through the documentation at all?

Comment: Yes, but if you think i missed something please point it out to me cause i really cant get what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I yet tried that (even if as i said i dont need to run any kind of task in the background) but unfortunately that doesnt change anything. As soon as i press home button my app fires `applicationWillTerminate` and closes completely.